# SQL @@RowCount on Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement. I would like to know if this select statement returns any rows or not. Based on the record count I would like to perform some other action.

I tried using `@@RowCount` to get the count but it does not seem to work properly with select statements.

Any suggestions on how this should be used or any other way I could perform my post task after select.

```
select    
    isnull(TotalHoursWorkedAmount, 0) / 26  
from    
    EmployeeStatus ESI
where   
    ESI.EmployeeCode = @employee_id
```

Adding the other piece

```
if @@ROWCOUNT=0
    SELECT dbo.fxGetAverage(@employee_id)
```

Comment: So all you need to know is if this query returns something or not?

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Comment: This is my guesswork but it looks like you want to return something *instead of* the first empty result. In this case you should check it using `if exists (select 1 from EmployeeStatus where EmployeeCode = @employee_id)`

Answer (score 5):

`@@ROWCOUNT` ***does*** work with select statements.  You did not show your attempt, so I can't really say what you're doing wrong.

but anyway, this would provide the rowcount as an example:

```
select    isnull(TotalHoursWorkedAmount, 0) / 26  
    from    EmployeeStatus ESI
    where   ESI.EmployeeCode = @employee_id

select @@rowcount
```

or store it in a variable:

```
declare @myCount int

select    isnull(TotalHoursWorkedAmount, 0) / 26  
    from    EmployeeStatus ESI
    where   ESI.EmployeeCode = @employee_id

set @myCount = @@rowcount
```

And as others stated, if it's just a true/false question - as opposed to do `x` if `y` number of rows, `z` if `v` number of rows - then you're better off doing an exists, ***unless you actually need the results of the select***.

```
if exists (    
    select  1
    from    EmployeeStatus ESI
    where   ESI.EmployeeCode = @employee_id
)
    begin
      print 'do stuff'
    end
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have updated my question with the updated code I am trying to work through.

Answer (score 2):

IF for some reason you cant get `@@rowcount` working you can use this query to check if you are getting any results. using if statement.

```
if not exists(select isnull(TotalHoursWorkedAmount, 0) / 26  from EmployeeStatus ESI where ESI.EmployeeCode = @employee_id)
     begin
          SELECT dbo.fxGetAverage(@employee_id) 
     end
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanna see if this exists and perform nothing if its in..else I wanna call a different function.

Comment: @Naga I have updated my answer to meet your requirement.