# MSSQL - Run second select if first returns 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to run the second select if the first does not return any data but what i tried, it does not work.

```
@Model varchar(50),
@UserId nvarchar(128),
@CountryId int

SELECT
        COUNT(1)
    FROM
        Product P
        JOIN Location PC ON P.ProductId = PC.ProductId
        JOIN Users USR ON USR.CountryId = PC.CountryId
    WHERE
        P.Model = @Model AND USR.Id = @UserId

if @@rowcount = 0
    SELECT
        COUNT(1)
    FROM
        Product P
        JOIN Location PC ON P.ProductId = PC.ProductId
    WHERE
        P.Model = @Model AND PC.CountryId = @CountryId
```

The are 2 results... how can i return only one?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first query can never return `0` rows.  It is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` so it always returns one row.

Comment: Is there any harm in always running the second query? Is it performance intensive or does it to any updates?

Comment: Do the first query alone, but switch to LEFT JOIN for the Users table, and have the  USR.Id = @UserId condition in the ON clause.

Comment: @jarlh Would be nice, but the first query has a UserID parameter, and the second query has a CountryID parameter.  All the same, I can think of a few ways to do this as a single query, but they're a bit messy.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, your question is about the value returned by the first query, not the number of rows.

If so, you can write this as one query:

```
WITH t1 AS (
      SELECT COUNT(1) as cnt
      FROM Product P JOIN
           Location PC
           ON P.ProductId = PC.ProductId JOIN
           Users USR
           ON USR.CountryId = PC.CountryId
      WHERE P.Model = @Model AND USR.Id = @UserId
     )
SELECT (CASE WHEN cnt > 0 THEN cnt
             ELSE (SELECT COUNT(1)
                   FROM Product P JOIN
                        Location PC
                        ON P.ProductId = PC.ProductId
                   WHERE P.Model = @Model AND PC.CountryId = @CountryId
        END) as cnt
FROM t
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to declare a variable `@Cnt` to get your query amount and check in the value.

```
@Model varchar(50),
@UserId nvarchar(128),
@CountryId int,
@Cnt INT

SELECT
    @Cnt = COUNT(1)
FROM
    Product P
    JOIN Location PC ON P.ProductId = PC.ProductId
    JOIN Users USR ON USR.CountryId = PC.CountryId
WHERE
    P.Model = @Model AND USR.Id = @UserId

if (@Cnt == 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @Cnt = COUNT(1)
    FROM
        Product P
        JOIN Location PC ON P.ProductId = PC.ProductId
    WHERE
        P.Model = @Model AND PC.CountryId = @CountryId
END

SELECT @Cnt
```

Comment: Is there any way to include this in another select? Like: Select a,b, {your answer}, c?

Comment: @JakeManet What do you mean in another select?

Comment: I need the entire query you wrote to be part as another select, this is not a stored procedure it is just a value for a column from another result.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get a @@rowcount with that select statement. See [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441744/sql-rowcount-on-select-statement) for clarification.

You can create a variable like below and use it in place of @@rowcount

```
SELECT @Count=COUNT(1)
```